# Python - video processing. How to: 1) change pixels value in videos (ie pixelated effect), and then 2) retrieve every single pixel's information

Tags: python, opencv, data-analysis, pixel, video-processing

This question is related to an actual science project.
**1.** The video will be done whit the medium of a white moving object against a black background surface. The final results will be close to a black/white output but I also need to render the video into an actual dual-color channel video (only displaying black and white pixels). I guess it should also be useful to delete/reduce noise (unrelated white pixels caused by light interference)
**2.** After that, I need to modify the pixels values in order to get a pixelated effect
**3**. at this very point, I need to obtain all the pixel values from all the frames, maybe arranged in a matrix fashion because I will need to perform some computational math on these matrices

let me show you an example:

```
 frame 1. (0 for black pixel values, 1 for white pixel values)
              01110000
              01111001
              01100011
              11101111
              01100000 
              10000000

frame 2.      00111000
              01011100
              11100000
              10010100
              10000101
              01010101
```

and so on...

Comment: you should post example data (images/video). unaltered data if possible. something that shows the problem and is usable in potential answers to demonstrate a solution. that ascii art hardly shows anything and you aren't even pointing out what it's supposed to show.

Answer (score 0):

```
# You could store it in a list like this:

frame1 = [.01110000, .01111001] # and so on. Because an int can't start on zero, I made these decilams

# To change the first item in this list do the following

frame1[0] = .01110011 # This will be the new value and the current list looks like this:
# frame1 = [.01110011, .01111001]

# To retrieve information about every element in the list simply use a for loop
n = -1
for element in frame1:
    n += 1
    element = frame1[n]
    print(element)
```

Comment: I really don't get what you're asking, so I did my best with the information at hand. How can I improve my answer to help you with your question?

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question. that would be @Enzo. I'm just here because I look for interesting questions in the opencv tag. I'll repeat my point: this answer doesn't even address the question.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you are right. Samuel was very kind but failed in giving back a useful answer.

Comment: @Samuel could you please tell me what you don't get in the question? try to be as specific as possible and I will do the same in return